# How to render different variables as you work your way down the page / through the script?

Tags: php, variables

I have a .php file that is rendering as a web page. Is there any way I could change a variable on the fly as the page renders?

Currently the page renders like this...

```
I love to eat oranges.
I love to eat oranges.
I love to eat oranges.
```

But I want it to render like this...

```
I love to eat oranges.
I love to eat apples.
I love to eat cheese.
```

Please see the sample code below...

```
<?php
$variable = "oranges";
?>

<?php
echo I love to eat $variable.
?>

<?php
$variable = "apples";
?>

<?php
echo I love to eat $variable.
?>

<?php
$variable = "cheese";
?>

<?php
echo I love to eat $variable.
?>
```

Comment: It's clear to me that PHP is/was the first programming language of most of its userbase...

Answer (score 2):

What is that, Programming 101?

```
<?php
foreach(array('apples','oranges','cheese') as $variable)
   echo "I love to eat $variable";
?>
```

Comment: It should be array([...]) as $variable.

Comment: `array(...) as $variable`, actually ;-)

Comment: yep, I'm doing javascript today, and didn't switch syntaxes :)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some quotes and semicolons:

```
<?php
$variable = "oranges";
?>

<?php
echo "I love to eat $variable.";
?>

<?php
$variable = "apples";
?>

<?php
echo "I love to eat $variable.";
?>

<?php
$variable = "cheese";
?>

<?php
echo "I love to eat $variable.";
?>
```

Here's another way to accomplish the same thing:

```
<?php
    $foods = array('oranges', 'apples', 'cheese');
    $index = 0;
    function getFood($next = FALSE) {
       if($next) {
           $str = $foods[++$index];
       } else {
           $str = $foods[$index];
       }
       return 'I love to eat ' . $str; 
    }
?>

...

<?php
    echo getFood();
?>

...

<?php
    echo getFood(true);
?>

...

<?php
    echo getFood();
?>
```

Comment: Or `echo "I love to eat " . $variable;`

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply.

I'll actually be needing each variable to be called a number of times before it changes again...

I love to eat oranges.
I love to eat oranges.
I love to eat oranges.

I love to eat apples.
I love to eat apples.

I love to eat cheese.
I love to eat cheese.
I love to eat cheese.
I love to eat cheese.

How would the script cater for this?

Comment: I know that it's a simplified example, but it won't work unless you set $index and $foods to be global variables (sic) in getNextFood().

Comment: I have tried putting the example code into a test .php file and It doesnt seem to work as is.

How do I set them to global variables as @piskvor suggested?